# Using of arrays in "C" printing array value with out using braces

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I have the following array:

```
int array[]={0,1,2,3,4};
```

I need to print the element `3` in the array list without using square brackets. So I should not use:

```
printf("%d",array[3]);
```

How do I achieve the same without using square brackets?

Comment: Got a homework question on pointer-math, do you?

Comment: is that your home work ... its good to read some book before ask the answer of your question ...

Comment: Wellcome on StackOverflow. Please show minimal effort when asking questions here. Use this site or your favorite search engine or read a good book.

Comment: You add 3 to the pointer and de-reference - `*(array+3)`

Answer (score 4):

`array[n]` is equivalent to `*(array + n)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `*(array + 3)`. This is different syntactically to `array[3]` but identical functionally.

The expression `array + 3` gives you the address of the fourth element in the array (index number 3), properly scaled for the element size. In other words, it's the same as taking the address of the element with `&(array[3])`.

Then the `*` dereferencing extracts the value at that address (of the correct type).

Answer (score 0):

To print the nth element , we know `arr[n-1] == *(arr+n-1)` . n-1 is being used because array in C are 0-indexed.